# Spring WS Maintaining Sessions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have published web service and client using spring boot and spring ws.
How can I manage sessions in Spring WS?
In JAX-WS in request context there is a property for that: `BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY`
I have tried to use session scopes from Spring but with no results...

Comment: Ideally your service should be stateless, generally trying to bolt stageful ness on a web service is more trouble then it is worth. Why do you need it?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that. But I got task on my uni that we have to implement a distributed classifier and between requests I have to store learnt object (I need run learning process only once) so I decided to use a sessions instead of serializing and saving in database. I tried to follow this: https://blogs.oracle.com/artf/entry/maintaining_sessions_using_jax_ws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the HTTP session by using the [TransportContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/common.html#transport-context):

```
TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
HttpServletConnection connection = (HttpServletConnection)context.getConnection();
HttpServletRequest request = connection.getHttpServletRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

But like M.Deinum said, Web services typically try to be stateless.